# find next greater element of a array in O(n) using one memset array and a single stack

Tags: c++, while-loop, stack, store, memset

my code is not working for Input:

```
10 3 *12* 4 2 9 13 0 8 11 1 7 5 6
```

Its Correct output is:

```
12 12 *13* 9 9 13 -1 8 11 -1 7 -1 6 -1
```

And Your Code's output is:

```
12 12 *-1* 9 13 13 -1 8 11 -1 7 -1 6 -1
```

what I can see, it is because in the `while(!s.empty() && a>s.top())` part I m not storing the index values for those elements for which `a<s.top()`, I'm not able to think of any way to do so.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        ll n;
        cin>>n;
        ll a,i,c[n];
        memset(c,-1,sizeof(c));
        stack <int> s;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>a;
            if(s.empty()){
                s.push(a);
            }
            else{
                if(a>s.top()){
                    int k=i;
                    while(!s.empty() && a>s.top()){
                        s.pop();
                        c[k-1]=a;
                        k--;
                    }
                    s.push(a);
                }
                else{
                    s.push(a);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            cout<<c[i]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more detail? like what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little bug in your code. When you update the value of `c[index]=value`, the `index` is not correct. While processing, you pop out some of the elements from the `stack` and push the value at the end(example: a value at a location of 10 can be pushed at anywhere between 0 and 10), but during stepping backward you don't know what was the correct location of that value.

So, I made slide changes in your code, kept track of the location of the value along with the value itself. So, when I update `c[index]=value`, I know the correct index of `s.top()` element.

```c
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        ll n;
        cin>>n;
        ll a,i,c[n];
        memset(c,-1,sizeof(c));
        stack < pair<int,int> > s;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>a;
            if(s.empty()){
                s.push({a,i});
            }
            else{
                if(a>s.top().first){
                    while(!s.empty() && a>s.top().first){
                        c[s.top().second]=a;
                        s.pop();
                    }
                    s.push({a,i});
                }
                else{
                    s.push({a,i});
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            cout<<c[i]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Input & Output:

```
1                                                                                                                               
15                                                                                                                              
14 10 3 12 4 2 9 13 0 8 11 1 7 5 6                                                                                              
-1 12 12 13 9 9 13 -1 8 11 -1 7 -1 6 -1
```

Comment: thanks ...i just wanted to know how to track down (store that particular index value) throughout the complete loop ...thanks again .